# How do you read the binary with gdb when no symbols available?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

How do you read binaries that have been stripped by `strip`?

That means,even `disas main` won't work.

How can one be able to read such binaries?

I saw this kind of requirement in a job description before.

Answer (score 1):

1. In GDB, use addresses (disas *0x80001000) or use register values (disas $pc $pc+10).
2. Use objdump -d. It doesn't care about symbols.
3. Use [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) :)